# Will applicationinsightConfig will cause application recycle

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-application-insights

I am using application insight SDK for logging exceptions. I am setting the exclusion/inclusion event type list in the applicationisightconfig file.

My question is that if i change applicationinsightconfig file to update exclusion list event list in run-time, will it recycle the application domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is that if i change applicationinsightconfig file to update exclusion list event list in run-time, will it recycle the application domain.

Based on my test, if you change the applicationinsightconfig to exclusion/inclusion event type list in the applicationisightconfig file. It will not affect you web application.

The web application will still work well.

The [Telemetry​Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.applicationinsights.extensibility.telemetryconfiguration.-ctor?view=appinsights-2.3.0-beta3#Microsoft_ApplicationInsights_Extensibility_TelemetryConfiguration__ctor_System_String_Microsoft_ApplicationInsights_Channel_ITelemetryChannel_) class will atuo get the parameter (you set in the .config) to run.

---

Update:

Based on my test, I found if you changed the setting in the applicationinsightconfig file, it will not be effective until the web application restart.

According to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-filtering-sampling#filtering-itelemetryprocessor), I created a custom processor to filter telemetry and register it with the SDK. All telemetry goes through your processor, and you can choose to drop it from the stream, or add properties.

Some part of the SuccessfulDependencyFilter:

```
public class SuccessfulDependencyFilter : ITelemetryProcessor
  {

    private ITelemetryProcessor Next { get; set; }

    // You can pass values from .config
    public string MyParamFromConfigFile { get; set; }

  // Example: replace with your own modifiers.
    private void ModifyItem (ITelemetry item)
    {
        item.Context.Properties.Add("app-version", "1." + MyParamFromConfigFile);
    }
```

The applicationinsightconfig file add below setting.

```
<TelemetryProcessors>
      <Add Type="WebApplication9.SuccessfulDependencyFilter, WebApplication9">
         <!-- Set public property -->
         <MyParamFromConfigFile>2-beta</MyParamFromConfigFile>
      </Add>
    </TelemetryProcessors>
```

It will add a custom type according to the applicationinsightconfig file.

After the application start I changed the setting as below:

[image]

But the custom property is still the "1.2-beta", not changed.

[image]

In my opinion, the applicationinsightconfig will be loaded when the application running. So if you changed the applicationinsightconfig setting, it will be effective after the application restarted.

Comment: do you have any documentation link to refer.

Comment: I did not find any documentation which says it explicitly.

Comment: This result is based on my test. I have run a web application on the azure and changed the AI config. The application could still run well.

Comment: Thanks @Brando Zhang. I have also tested this with my application, its working as expected. But searching for some documentation now, that confirms it. Actually i need to make decision to use this approach.

Comment: Based on my test, I found if you changed the setting in the applicationinsightconfig file, it will not be effective until the web application restart.

Comment: Any update?If you feel my answer is useful /helpful.Please mark it as an answer so that other folks could benefit from it.